# A lower bound on an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm stuck on a problem and the last piece of the puzzle is to show the following. Given $f$ a continuous function on $[0,1]$ does it follow that,

$$\int^{1}_{0} (1-t)f(t) dt \geq \min_{x\in[0,1]}f(x).$$

Many thanks

Comment: Try with a constant function $f(x)=1$. The LHS is $1/2$ and the RHS is $1$.

Comment: Many Thanks. A little bit silly of me in retrospect!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha = min_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)$

We have $ \alpha ≤ f(t) \ \ \forall t \in [0,1]$

And $1-t ≥ 0 \ \ \forall t \in [0,1]$

Then $(1-t)\alpha ≤ (1-t)f(t) \ \ \forall t \in [0,1]$

Thus by monotony of the integral we have

$\int_{0}^{1} (1-t)\alpha dt ≤ \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)f(t)dt \implies$

$ \alpha \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)dt ≤ \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)f(t)dt$

As $\int_{0}^{1} (1-t)dt = 1$

Then $\alpha ≤ \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)f(t)dt$

We are done

Comment: Thank you very much! But your third to last line is incorrect, $\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)dt = \frac{1}{2}$ but still this was useful to me!

Comment: Oooh I'm sorry! You are right, I miscalculated the integral